# Warning- AWS Credentials exposed on Google Play Console

Tags: amazon-s3, google-play, android-keystore, android-security, google-play-console

I have my app published on PlayStore. I am getting this warning on my Play Console that my AWS Credentials have been exposed and i won't be able upload new apk after 12 November 2018 if the problem persists. I use the credentials for uploading images to Amazon S3. The credentials are hard coded right now.
So i need to know what should be the way to rectify this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also facing the same issue, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon have a whole blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/what-to-do-if-you-inadvertently-expose-an-aws-access-key/) on dealing with this problem, and [a page on best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html).

Essentially you need to revert the old credentials, and use [Amazon Cognito to control access](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-the-amazon-cognito-credentials-provider/).

An updated link on cognito lives [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html)

Comment: Yes, @Nick Fortescue amazon have whole blog post and using that created IAM user and add S3 policy by creating custom policy.
Used Amzon cognito in old code than what I have to change in my current implementation